# Disable load function untill button is selected in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi this is an odd question and i will try to ask it correctly. I have a function using javascript called load canvas.

```
function loadCanvas(canvas) {

relevant code here...

}
```

I also have a normal button called btn.

```
<button class="btn" type="button">Play!</button>
```

I am wondering can i disable the function until the play button is selected? The function is for a game using javascript. So on load there isnt anything there until i press play then it appears!

any ideas/help please?

Comment: Call loadCanvas on click of this play button ?

Comment: @AmitJS94 Yes kind of like that, at the moment i have it loading straight in as the page loads up. I want to disable until the button is selected

Comment: It's a function. It isn't going to do anything until some other code calls it. So don't call it until you want it to run.

Comment: Some other function is calling loadCanvas, that's why it's executing. You can debug this by checking the stack in the console to see which function is calling loadCanvas.

Comment: Like @AmitJS94 said you need to call function while play button click.

Comment: @AmitJS94 Yes its this   <script type="text/javascript">
   loadCanvas("game");
  </script>

Comment: but i want to be able to have it for onlick function

Comment: @DonaldBury — So remove the script element that calls it and bind a click a handler. What's the problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You got to do following:

```js
function loadCanvas(game) {
 alert('loading canvas');
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="loadCanvas('game')">Play!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var loadCanvas=  function (canvas) {

             relevant code here...

         } 

    $("#test").on('click',loadCanvas()); // using jquery

document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",loadCanvas()); // using javascript

<button class="btn" id="test" type="button">Play!</button>

})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issue because other method is triggering the function you can add a flag with a boolean and turn it on when you click..

Something like that:

The button don't change at all

```
<button class="btn" type="button">Play!</button>
```

The js code with this change:

```
var buttonClicked = false;
function loadCanvas(canvas) {
    if(buttonClicked){
        relevant code here...
    }
}
```

And in the on click function add this before call the function:

```
buttonClicked = true;
```

At the end your js should look like this:

```
var buttonClicked = false;
function loadCanvas(canvas) {
    if(buttonClicked){
        relevant code here...
    }
} 

$(".btn").click(function(){
    buttonClicked  = true;
    var canvas = ...;
    loadCanvas(canvas );
});
```

**EDIT**

If you have more buttons with the class .btn you should use an id and change the selector of the `.click()` with the selector of the id instead of the class selector

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments `<script type="text/javascript"> loadCanvas("game"); </script>` You are calling the function as soon as the page loads. So you will have to change it to:

```
<button class="btn play-button" type="button">Play!</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
         $('.play-button').click(function(e){
        loadCanvas("game");}
        );
    </script>
```

If you are not using jquery you will have to handle the click event by javascript.